# Custom line item types without a product reference field

Tags: 7, commerce

Let me start by saying I am aware of this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product

This module works great for custom line item types that need to reference a product, however (correct me if I am wrong) this module can't be used to create custom line item types that do NOT reference a product.

I need a custom line item type, that doesn't reference a product. Which lead to the discovery of this:

http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_examples/tree/line_item_example/line_item_example.module

Utilizing `hook_commerce_line_item_type_info()` I am able to successfully create a custom line item type, and have it automatically come with the Unit and Total price fields automatically.

All is well so far...

Now if I use the Drupal UI to add a custom field (e.g. an entity reference field, not a product reference field) to this custom line item type, I am able to do this without issue. I can add as many fields as I want.

Now for the problem...

However, when I use the admin order form and try to manually add this custom line item type to an order, the custom field(s) don't show up in the form.

I see from the documentation that I could implement the `configuration`, `add_form` and `add_form_submit` callbacks. But I figured any fields added through the UI would automatically show up on the form(s).

What is going on here? Must I implement the form code-side for all fields on the custom entity type?

Comment: There is also the (now "deprecated") module [Commerce Custom Line Items (Types)](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_line_items). It allows to create line item types without product. Worth to give it a try, and see what to do from there.

Comment: Sorry, just tried myself, it does not really help. Product reference field still there.

Comment: It seems you need to manually add widgets for these fields in the add_form callback. Would be nice if we can find a way to automate this.

Answer (score 2):

A line item **must** have a product associated with it. Rules, Commerce Cart, and Commerce Shipping all depend on having the `commerce_product` field on a line item object.

Comment: From my testing this a 100% true - however why does [`hook_commerce_line_item_type_info()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.api.php/function/hook_commerce_line_item_type_info/7) have a **product** boolean?

Comment: Because a line can be explicitly defined as not a product. A number of modules do this: [commerce_account_balance](http://dgo.to/commerce_account_balance), [commerce_exactor](http://dgo.to/commerce_exactor), and [commerce_payment_split](http://dgo.to/commerce_payment_split) to name 3. Anything that _is_ a product must have the correct fields (from the docs, re: the product boolean attribute): "If set to TRUE, the line item type must also contain the fields added to the base product line item type, commerce_product".